# Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse as an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have to prove that $A^+A$ (where $A^+=\overline{R^t}\left(R\overline{R^t}\right)^{-1}\overline{Q^t}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of A, with $A=QR$ through QR decomposition) is the orthogonal projection on the columns of A* (A* being the conjugate transpose of A). My problem is: I have no idea where to start. What exactly must I show to prove that it's an orthogonal projection?

Comment: What are the defining properties of $A^+$?  What are the defining properties of an orthogonal projection?  In other words, what *minimization* problem can you relate both of these to?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't given us much context here, my best guess for the "right approach" is as follows: using what you know about the pseudoinverse and projections, note that both matrices are such that for a given vector $y$: the output $\hat y = A^+Ay$ (or $\hat y = Q^*(RR^*)^{-1}Q^*y$) is the vector $\hat y = A^*x$ that minimizes $\|A^*x - y\|$.